# Wireguard client configuration file - confidential values

Tags: confidentiality, secrets-management, wireguard

Given a Wireguard client configuration file, I guess some of the fields shouldn't be shared with just anyone, like the private key, right?

Is there any other field that should be treated as a confidential value? I want to add the client config file to a repo for automation in my environment.

Comment: So, can you be more specific? What fields? address, DNS, server endpoint IP, and allowed IPs?

Comment: Under Interface I have: Address, PrivateKey and DNS.
Under Peer, I have PublicKey, PresharedKey, Endpoint, AllowedIPs and PersistentKeepalive.
Which of the mentioned fields should be kept secret?

Comment: Right, so besides the keys (which you identified) you have: IPs, DNS server, and the PersistentKeepalive setting. Do you have the need to keep any of those IPs secret? What would be the impact iff they were known?

Comment: I think the PersistentKeepalive is definitely not a secret.
I'm doubting about the rest though.

Comment: Right, that's why I was omitting that. It boils down to the IPs. Would exposing those IPs present a problem? In most cases, that would not be a big issue, but in some contexts, it would.

Comment: OK so the PublicKey and the PresharedKey should be kept secret as well, right?

Comment: In this case, even the public key should be kept secret (that's not always the case of public keys).

Comment: @schroeder What's the reasoning for keeping the pubkey secret? Genuinely wondering...

Answer (score 0):

The `PrivateKey` and `PresharedKey` fields are secrets.

The rest of the fields in a WireGuard config file could conceivably be useful to an adversary for reconnaissance purposes (eg to compile a list of which users have access to a particular system, or to find IPs to DDoS, etc) -- but they're not secrets from the perspective of WireGuard's design (ie their disclosure would not give a meaningful advantage to an adversary trying to decrypt/alter/spoof WireGuard messages).